# How do I make a custom class available to client through a web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, .net-4.0, asmx

I have a simple web service (asmx)built in net framework 4.0 that has multiple custom classes defined. I would like to know how to make these classes available to the client. one of the classes would be returned from a method but the others are used to pass information to the web service so the client needs to know what is included in the class. for instance

```
Public Class clsAddress
Public AddressType As TypeAddress
Public Location As TypeLocation
Public Line1 As String
Public Line2 As String
Public City As String
Public State As String
Public ZipCode As String
Public ZipPlus4 As String
```

End Class

So the client would do something like this to send the info to the webservice:

```
  Dim tempAddressInfo As New clsAddress
        tempAddressInfo.AddressType = cboAddressType.SelectedIndex 'TypeAddress.current
        tempAddressInfo.Location = cboLocation.SelectedIndex 'TypeLocation.USA
        tempAddressInfo.Line1 = txtAddress1.Text
        tempAddressInfo.Line2 = txtAddress2.Text
        tempAddressInfo.City = txtCity.Text
        tempAddressInfo.State = txtState.Text
        tempAddressInfo.ZipCode = txtZipCode.Text
        tempAddressInfo.ZipPlus4 = txtZipPlus4.Text
        mclsIdVerify.pAddressInfo = tempAddressInfo
```

I saw something about returning a custom class using the XMLInclude attribute in a method that returns the class. what needs to be completed so the custom classes can be sent and received by the client.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally leave a question like this to someone with more knowledge but as no one has attemped to give you an answer I'll give it a shot.

I think to be able to convert your class into an object state that can be stored or transfered across a network it needs to be serealizable. This allows it to be reconstructed at the other end.

Try putting  _ above your class definition.

Even if this doesnt help hopefully it gives your something to look into.